# SQL commands not found when run through shell script in Jenkins pipeline code

Tags: oracle, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I'm trying to run following code in Jenkins pipeline through shell script -

```
sh'''
            export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME
            export ORACLE_SID=orcl
            cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
            echo "Starting oracle database..."
            sqlplus /nolog
            conn sys/password as sysdba
            shutdown abort
            startup
            exit success
            echo "done"
            '''
```

But this results into an error -

`SQL> + conn sys/password as sysdba /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/Database_Error_Handling@tmp/durable-ca459d3c/script.sh: line 7: conn: command not found`

None of the commands are not found however same command works fine from the machine. Can you please help to understand what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below script and replace the script which you want to execute in the sqlplus prompt

```
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
echo "Starting oracle database..."
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus "/nolog"  **<<  EOF**

select name from v$database;

exit;

-- Replace the above 2 lines which you want to execute it in sqlplus

**EOF**

echo "done"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! THis helped and saved my time as I could not figured it out easily.